# random mask reversible after homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, randomness, paillier

I would like to know if this process is feasible under homomorphic encryption, ideally under ***paillier*** or any other **additive** scheme

1. Apply a mask *X* to obfuscate a message *A* ie. *Am = A (op) X* where *(op)* can be +, x, ...
2. Homomorphically encrypt *Am* => *E(Am)*
3. Remove *X* from *E(Am)* in order to obtain *E(A)* **without any decryption (without knowing the private key)**

*A* can be a matrix, vector, ...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to do blinded encryption (that is, encryption in such a way that the encryptor does not know what he is encrypting).

It is certainly possible with Paillier.  Here is one way:

- The (op) will be multiplication modulo $n$ the Paillier modulus (which is in the public key).
- To mask, we pick a random $r$ relatively prime to $n$, and compute $Am = A \cdot r \bmod n$.  We can see that, if we selected $r$ uniformly, then $Am$ is distributed independently of $A$ (except for values not relatively prime to $n$)
- We ask the encryptor to take $Am$ to compute $E(Am)$
- To unmask, we compute $rinv = r^{-1} \bmod n$, and then homomorphically compute $E(rinv \cdot Am)$; this Paillier, this is done by computing $E(Am)^{rinv} \bmod n = E(A)$.

One drawback to this is that it doesn't actually mask the value $A=0$; is that a concern?

If it is, you can still do it by asking the encryptor to perform two masked encrypted operations.

First, you generate two random values $r, s$, making sure that neither is $0$

Then, you have the encryptor encrypt the values $A-s$ and $r\cdot s$, producing $E(A-s)$ and $E(r \cdot s)$.  Then, you use the above procedure to recover $E(s)$ from $E(r \cdot s)$.  Then, you homomorphically add $E(s)$ to $E(A-s)$, producing $E(A)$

You could just generate $E(s)$ yourself with $s$ and the public key.  However, if you could perform encryption yourself, you could just generate $E(A)$ from $A$, and it would appear you wanted to avoid that...

Comment: Thanks, and r can be of any dimension ?

Comment: @witdev: For Paillier, it would be a value between 1 and $n-1$,  If the value $A$ is a vector, then you would have a vector of $r$'s, and blind encrypt each element of the vector separately.

Comment: Thanks again,
1. Could it be a vector with a different $r$ in each of its elements or you mean a vector with the same $r$ repeated ?
2. I found in http://shorturl.at/jZ026 that the equivalence of $E(a [mult] b)$ is $E(a)^{E(b)}$, while you used $E(Am)^{rinv}  mod  n$ .. what is the difference ?

Comment: @witdev: no, using the same $r$ would leak information; use a different random $r$ each time.

Comment: I have no idea what that url is - it doesn''t resolve for me

Comment: Actually it's http://shorturl.at/jZ026, it points to google books ... anyway, thanks a lot .. I think that the equivalence I found was between ciphertexts, while the one you used is between a ciphertext and a plaintext ... thanks again.

Comment: Since multiplication between ciphertexts in not allowed in Paillier, how can we perform $E(Am)^{rinv}$ ?

Comment: @witdev: how homomorphic addition is done with Pailler is by multiplying the ciphertexts; that is, $E(A+B) = E(A)E(B) \bmod n$.  So, to compute $E(rinv \cdot Am)$, we raise the ciphertext $E(rinv)$ to the $rinv$-th power

Comment: yes, the property you mentioned is correct but AFAIK it should be read in the inverse sens, ie. we can obtain the result of $E(A)E(B)$ only by computing $E(A+B)$, but not the opposite ... same thing applies on $E(A)^b$ which is obtained via $E(A.b)$ .. please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @witdev: we can compute the value $E(A)E(B)$ by taking the two values $X=E(A)$ and $Y = E(B)$, and computing the value $X \times Y \bmod n$ by plugging $X, Y, n$ into our favorite bignum calculator (e.g. python).  The result is a valid encryption of $A+B$ (obviously, not the only one - Paillier is nondeterministic, and so there are lots of valid encryptions of any specific plaintext.